# Python Pandas - filter groups based on existence of value in group

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group a dataframe by one column and then filter out all groups that do not contain a particular value in another column.

So eg here's my dataframe:

```
A  B
1 False
1 True
2 False
2 False
3 True
3 False
4 False
```

I want to group by column A, and then remove all groups which do not contain a True in column B (so only leaving groups for 1 and 3 in the example).

The code I'm trying is:

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x:True in x['B'])
```

However, this is returning empty. Why is this not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is filter all `A` values with `True` in `B` column and pass to [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership by original `A` column and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['A'].isin(df.loc[df.B, 'A'])]
```

Or you can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with test if at least one `True` per groups by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('any')]
print (df1)
   A      B
0  1  False
1  1   True
4  3   True
5  3  False
```

Your solution is possible change with test one `True` per group by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html), but if large DataFrame or many groups it is slowiest:

```
df1 = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].any())
```

Comment: That's got it - I used the last option - not a very big DataFrame. Thank you!